# REG EXPORT HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet - error on windows

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi, driver

I am testing a windows driver software. When the test fails, I have to attach registry data to the bug.

I get

```
"ERROR: Unable to write to the file. There may be a disk or file system error."
```

when I run the following command

REG EXPORT HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet .\Reg-data\CCS.reg

(I am running the command in Administrator mode).

This happens very infreqently. Can this be caused by driver software? or could this be a generic OS issue?

Comment: You should be getting and event log, can you confirm?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem when calling "reg export" (followed by a registry key and a path to write to) from a CMD file. The exact same command consistently worked when pasted to the same CMD prompt where the cmd script was run from, and consistently did not work from within the script.

I couldn't find the reason, but I worked around the problem by replacing "reg export" with "regedit /e", beware that you need to switch the position of the file path and registry key. This command works both inside and outside a cmd script.

So, here is before and after:

```
::reg export /y HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318} "%temp%\myfilename"

regedit /e /y "%temp%\myfilename" HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}
```

PS. Both commands will create a file in UTF16 format.

Answer (score 1):

You are not providing a destination filename to tell `REG` where to write the exported data to.

```
C:\>reg export /?

REG EXPORT KeyName **FileName** [/y]

  Keyname    ROOTKEY[\SubKey] (local machine only).
    ROOTKEY  [ HKLM | HKCU | HKCR | HKU | HKCC ]
    SubKey   The full name of a registry key under the selected ROOTKEY.

  FileName   The name of the disk file to export.

  /y       Force overwriting the existing file without prompt.

Examples:

  REG EXPORT HKLM\Software\MyCo\MyApp AppBkUp.reg
    Exports all subkeys and values of the key MyApp to the file AppBkUp.reg
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I do provide the destination path
REG EXPORT HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet .\RegData\CCS.reg

Comment: Does your driver have permission to access and write to `.\RegData\CCS.reg`?

Comment: yes, teh driver has the permission.
I ran the command from teh command prompt. It still fails

Comment: Does the `CCS.reg` file already exist? If so, have you tried including the `/y` parameter to overwrite the file without prompting? Do you have the same problem if you use `REGEDIT /E` instead of `REG EXPORT`? If you are still having problems, then it has to be related to the file itself, maybe you really don't have permissions you think you have, or the drive is failing, or something. The fact that you can reproduce the error manually means the problem is likely not with `REG` itself.

Answer (score 0):

To make it short, it should be:

```
Reg Export "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags" "G:\reg\Shell_Bags.reg"
```